# How to use konva in nestjs

Tags: node.js, canvas, konvajs, konva

I need konva to run on nodejs. I used this documentation from the creators themselves.
doc - https://github.com/konvajs/konva#4-nodejs-env

I myself use nestjs.

error [image]

package.json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the import

```
import Konva from 'konva';
```

on

```
const Konva = require('konva/cmj').default;
```